# How can I get gmail messages for a specific label like fetch only for chat messages

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, gmail, gmail-api

I am working with `gmail` query "`GTLQueryGmail`" and I get top `100 mails` with following code ->

```
  GTLQueryGmail *query = [GTLQueryGmail queryForUsersMessagesList];
query.maxResults = 100;

[self.service executeQuery:query
                  delegate:self
         didFinishSelector:@selector(displayResultMessageListWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:)];
```

Using this I am getting all mails like "`Chat`", "`Inbox`", "`Sent`", etc.

But I want mails from a specific category like "Chat" only.

So I am Looking for a query through which I can get mails separately for a specific Label Id.

Also I want to query for mails received from some sender mail id like " xxxxx@walkover.in".

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Also I want to query for mails received from some sender mail id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the API Explorer at the bottom of the [Gmail API reference](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) to see everything you can configure in your request.

As you can see, you need to send a parameter `labelIds` if you only want to list messages with a certain label:

```
GTLQueryGmail *query = [GTLQueryGmail queryForUsersMessagesList];
query.labelIds = 'CHAT';
```

You can also do a search in the same way you search in the gmail client, with the `q` parameter:

```
GTLQueryGmail *query = [GTLQueryGmail queryForUsersMessagesList];
query.q = 'from:xxxxx@walkover.in';
```

Comment: Just to add on this you can also check  [Users.messages: modify](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify) on adding LabelIds.